# Is this a valid proof that $A \cup (B \cap C) \not= (A \cup B) \cap C$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing

I'm currently taking an introductory proof-writing course, and was wondering whether the following proof is incorrect:

*Prove or disprove the following statement: if $A$, $B$ and $C$ are sets then $A \cup (B \cap C) = (A \cup B) \cap C$.*

*Proof.* The statement is false. Suppose we have some $x \in A$ such that $x \not\in B$ and $x \not\in C$. Then $x$ is an element of $A \cup (B \cap C)$, but is not an element of $(A \cup B) \cap C$.

Is there some issue with "supposing" such an $x$ exists in this way? This question was marked wrong because it is "not reasonable", I asked for further clarification and this is the response I got:

*The question asked you to prove but not just to provide explanation. You can use digits or numbers to prove this.  For example, A=(1,2,3), B=(3, 4), C=(2) to prove this question which is more detailed rather than just to explain.*

I'm open to being wrong here, I'm just having a hard time understanding the TA's explanations and would appreciate some outside feedback. Thanks!

Comment: I guess the marker is looking for a proof that the case $x\in A \land x\not\in B \land x\not\in C$ is possible, which (again) could be an example.

Comment: This seems right.

Answer (score 4):

There is an issue with supposing that there is an $x$ such that $x \in A$ but $x \notin B$ and $x \notin C$.

If at some point in a proof you assume that a certain object exists, then you need to ensure that the object does exist, otherwise you've only proved that if such and such an object exists, then some statement is true.

EDIT:

Now in this case, what you are assuming is correct, even if it could be phrased a bit better, e.g. "Suppose there are sets $A$, $B$, $C$ with $x \in A$, $x \notin B$ and $x \notin C$." But until you've established that it is correct, e.g. in this case, produced a concrete example, you haven't produced a proof.

The reason why it's called a "proof-writing course" is that there is a big difference between having some kind of heuristic argument that something is correct versus having a formally correct proof. Indeed, there have been many cases in the history of mathematics where convincing heuristic arguments have turned out to be subtly mistaken. The course is teaching you the skill of how to approach converting heurstic arguments into formal proofs.

This might seem pedantic or tedious when dealing with questions about elementary set theory. But when you move on to courses on more subtle topics like real analysis, where you have to be much more careful when you assume that such and such an object exists, you will need this skill to have become second nature.

Comment: "Can you think of a case where there can be no  such that ∈ but ∉ and ∉?" We can definitely construct some sets $A$, $B$ and $C$ such that this doesn't hold, but because all we're told about $A$, $B$ and $C$ is that they're sets aren't we just saying that there _exists_ some sets such that the assumption is true? In retrospect a concrete counter-example would have been more clear for sure.

Comment: In any particular proof save very fundamental ones aren't we almost always making _some_ unstated assumptions? If you were asked to prove the irrationality of sqrt(2) for example you probably wouldn't feel the need to explicitly argue that the square root exists (so long as any variable that we're taking the root of was assumed to be positive).

Comment: In the case of the proof I offered the only assumption was that (there exists some sets $A$, $B$, and $C$ such that there exists an element $x$ such that $x \in A$ and $x \not\in B$ and $x \not\in C$). Obviously this would have been easy to demonstrate with a counter-example, but outside the context of an introductory proof course I'm not sure many people would take issue with that assumption.

Comment: @Wabberjockey You are absolutely right that outside such a course, every mathematician would accept your reasoning. But that's because they all went through some kind of intro to proofs and are now aware that a) a counterexample is needed and b) that they and any other mathematician are immediately able to provide one. In that course, however, your awareness of these things is being trained.

Answer (score 3):

Your proof looks great and even demonstrates exactly when the two sets differ: when $A \setminus (B \cup C) \neq \varnothing$. In my opinion, if the TA wanted an explicit counterexample, that should have been stated more clearly in the prompt. Notice that the number $1$ in the counterexample provided is precisely your element $x$.